# How to reference a variable in regex URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, rest, express

```js
router.get("/(A|B)/account/", async (req, res) => {});
```

How to do I reference the `(A|B)` inside of the async function?

Comment: You should be using parameters. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: But with parameters it will match anything, not just A or B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your route responsibility is getting account information of only A or B. So  let's change your router path to `/account/:name(A|B)`, then your express router will look like this:

```
router.get("/account/:name(A|B)", async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.params; // A or B
});
```

Only 2 kinds of requests are handled by this router:

```
GET /account/A
or
GET /account/B
```